# Optimizing Disabled Game Objects in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am creating a infinite terrain generation system in Unity that instantiates "chunks" of terrain around the player and deactivates them once they are no longer visisble. (See images bellow)

[image: Chunks of terrain are loaded around the player]

After the player wanders around for a bit many of these chunks will be instantated and later have thier GameObjects deactivated. My problem is that all of the deactivaed chunks sitting in the scene are taking up computational resources.

Now the obvious solution would be to destroy the chunks that are no longer visible so that unity no longer loads them, however the chunks need to exist in memory in order to be re-enabled when the player is close enough to enable them again. This would work, however each chunk that gets loaded has data associated with it that needs to stay persistant.

Is there any way to optimize disabled GameObjects or Destroy GameObjects and keep their data?

Comment: It sounds interesting. Define the bare minimum data that makes a chunk unique, call it D.  For example, if it's only the color that makes it unique then D is just the color value.  D should be much smaller than the prefab. Save D before you destroy an instance, and after you instantiate a new one, configure it from its value of D.  D can either be stored in memory or file, but if you need these values to persist across games you will need use files for that.

Comment: Something else you could try is have a maximum number of map chunks allowable, and when you exceed that limit you can destroy the most distant disabled chunk to keep the memory usage down. As suggested by dynamicbutter though, you'll want to save map chunk data so if it is destroyed, it can be instantiated again and set back to the same state. You could save this data either when you're destroying a map chunk, or whenever things change on the map.

Comment: You may have spotted there is a tool to do this available from procedural worlds. They seem to do a form of asset loading and unloading

Comment: @dynamicbutter thank you so much for your comments! I am working on a solution now. I will post an answer once I get everything working. It sounds like using a file would be the best option in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume by disabled GameObjects you mean that they're disabled with GameObject.SetActive(false), which unfortunately is the most practical/optimal way of doing it while keeping it in RAM. What you'll have to do is serialize the chunk so that you can save it to the disk, so that you can load it later when the player gets close to it again.

There is no simple way of doing this, you'll just have to manually figure out exactly what you need to save, write a function that can save a chunk with this data, and a different function to generate a chunk from this data.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I meant by having the object disabled. I am implementing a solution now based on this answer!

Answer (score 1):

You can use Object pooling. Create 2 or more(as per requirements) objects at start of each type of chunk and keep them disabled. Generate a PoolManager to keep track of the chunk. You can make a distance based logic to command PoolManager which chunk need to be enabled when and at what place.